# How to pass a Dictionary to Objective-C method in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary

I need to pass a Dictionary to a Objective-C method in Swift. In Swift the code is like this:

```
let modelData: Dictionary<String, [Double]> = getModelData()
result = myChilitags.estimate3D(configAt: configFilePath, forModel: modelData);
```

(The configure file has nothing to do with this problem, just ignore it.)

I used a `.h` file:

```
@interface myChilitags : NSObject
+ (nonnull UIImage *)estimate3D:configAt:(NSString *)configFilePath forModel:(nonnull NSDictionary*) modelData;
@end
```

The question is that I need to do something with the `modelData` in the Objective-C method `estimate3D` but I don't know what to do after I passed the Dictionary value `modelData` to the method.

I tried to just print the modelData value but all that came out was:

```
1
```

I also tried to print the value in the Dictionary like:

```
std::cout << modelData["face001"] << std::endl;
```

I am pretty sure that there is a key `"face001"` in the dictionary but the result was still:

```
1
```

I know it must have something to do with NSDictionary and Dictionary but I just don't know what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. OP's example is *Objective-C++*, not Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a Dictionary in Swift is struct, an NSDictionary is class.
Objective-C is not type-safe so it doesn't show an error.
If you try to do the same in Swift, it will tell you
`Cannot assign value of type '[String : [Double]]' to type 'NSDictionary'`

```
let swiftDictionary = [String: [Double]]()
var nsDictionary = NSDictionary()
nsDictionary = swiftDictionary //shows error
```

So you have to convert the Swift dictionary to an NSDictionary.

```
let modelData: Dictionary<String, [Double]> = getModelData()
let nsModelData = NSDictionary(dictionary: modelData)
result = myChilitags.estimate3D(configAt: configFilePath, forModel: nsModelData);
```